# How to set value if object exists - if not intialize and set object in javascript?

Tags: javascript

I have the following result:

```
const mainResult = { result: 1234}
```

I have the following also:

```
const allResults = {};
```

I want to set `allResults.results.mainResult = mainResult`;

However I won't know if `allResults.results` exists or not.  How do I create `allResults.results` as an object if it doesn't exist and set it to mainResults - or just set it if `allResults.results.mainResults` exists?

Is there a way to do this in one line?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know whether there is a genuine one-line solution, but I have a forced one-line solution, which is the combination of [Logical nullish assignment (??=)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_nullish_assignment) and [Logical AND (&&) operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_AND)

```js
const mainResult = { result: 1234 }
const allResults = {};

(allResults.results ??= {}) && (allResults.results.mainResult = mainResult)

console.log(allResults)
```

```js
const mainResult = { result: 1234 }
const allResults = { results: { otherResult: 5678 } };

(allResults.results ??= {}) && (allResults.results.mainResult = mainResult)

console.log(allResults)
```

As @Bergi suggested, we could make it shorter

```js
const mainResult = { result: 1234 }
const allResults = {};

(allResults.results ??= {}).mainResult = mainResult

console.log(allResults)
```

Comment: No reason for logical AND here. You should've just used the comma operator if you want a forced single expression, i.e. `(allResults.results ??= {}), (allResults.results.mainResult = mainResult);`. But that's all totally unnecessary - just write `(allResults.results ??= {}).mainResult = mainResult;`!

Comment: @Bergi thank you for the suggestion, I'll update in the answer

Answer (score 0):

Wondering why this won't work? Since we just want to write/overwrite it and not expand the object if it exists.

```
const mainResult = { result: 1234 };
const allResults = {};
allResults.results = { mainResult };
console.log(allResults);
```